# What is a solution to this "unintended reference comparison" error?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, if-statement

```
        if (submit.Content.Equals("Submit"))
```

I'm trying to test if the content in a button called submit = "submit".  However, this code doesn't work.

Comment: found fix, change code to : if ( ((String)submit.Content) == "Submit" )

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have "==" before? Using Equals should have worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the `Content` property is `Object`, so you will be calling the `Object.Equals` method rather than the `String.Equals` method. The string method compares string values, while the object method only compares the references.

You can just apply the method to the string instead to make it a string comparison instead of a reference comparison:

```
if ("Submit".Equals(submit.Content))
```

Comment: if "Submit" is interned (which you would expect it to be), wouldn't Object.ReferenceEquals also return true?

Comment: @MattDavey: Only if the string in the content is also interned.

Comment: if it was an identical string it would also be a reference to the interned instance? Or can you have two identical strings, one of which is intened and one not?

Comment: @MattDavey: You can certainly have identical strings that are separate objects. A string can for example be created by building it from smaller strings, like `new StringBuilder("Sub").Append("mit").ToString()`, which is not interned.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up - I kinda assumed that every time a new immutable string was created the CLR would do a look up to the intern pool. I now realise that is only the case with literal strings :)